# How to show all the build history or recent 5 builds using Jelly in Jenkins

Tags: build, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly, email-ext

I was wondering if it is possible to send all the recent build history or atleast the latest 5 builds in Jenkins using the plugin email-ext. I am currently using Jelly as my email template. How am I going to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

$BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS in subject gives the result is either failed or success

coming to your question i think ${CHANGES_SINCE_LAST_SUCCESS-BUILD_NUMBER -BUILD_STATUS}

This may or may not work but you can changes these default token as you wish by using advance option.